# Closed views are not disposed of in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When I click on the close symbol of an Eclipse view, the view is not visible anymore. But when I reopen the view programmatically again, the view seems not beeing disposed of correctly, because the view isn't newly created but somehow loaded.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening, what are the background processes of Eclipse, that lead o this problem?

Comment: The `dispose` method of the view is definitely called when you click the close view symbol and `createPartControl` is called when you show it again. Show us your code and what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view will only be correctly disposed, when you close it in every perspective. Therefore iterate over all perpectives an close the view there programmatically to ensure the functionality you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

A view is only disposed of when the last instance is closed.

If you close a view that is also shown in another perspective, the view is only hidden. Just after you close all instances, the view is disposed of.